# Scaling Django File Uploading

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I have recently created a Inline form Set to manage files uploading. 
My objective is hosting my files on AWS.

I have a model House. The model has a related Model HouseDocument where files related to a house are stored. HouseDocument has House as a ForeigKey.

This is the view :

```
def manage_files(request, house_slug):
    house = House.objects.get(slug=house_slug)
    HouseDocumentInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(House, HouseDocument, fields=('document',))
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = BookInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=house)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(house.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        formset = BookInlineFormSet(instance=author)
    return render(request, 'manage_books.html', {'formset': formset})
```

I'm not seeking a code example. I seek advice on how big web applications handle file uploading when they have a lot of concurrent users ? 
Any useful documentation ?

Does Django IO blocking makes file upload complicated ?